# Adding new classes to existing javadoc

Tags: java, javadoc

I have already created javadocs for many classes by executing the command:
`javadoc xx.java xxx.java`. 
Now I have following 2 questions:

1. Suppose I am creating a new class `xy.java` and want to add its javadoc to the already existing javadoc. How can I do that? Do I need to do `javadoc xx.java xxx.java xy.java`? Do I need to do this for every new class I create?
2. What do I need to do so that my package and its classes appear along side the offical java API docs? So that I just need to open 1 API doc to view docs for both java standard library classes and my custom classes?

Comment: Please ask one question per question. I think 1 could be easily answerable, but 2 is probably not possible (or at least very complex).

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid typing each file name you can use

- packagenames or
- wildcards for filename patterns

like this (on Windows, on Linux use forward slashes):

```
javadoc com.me.myproject
javadoc com\me\myproject\*.java
```

But be aware that you have to declare subpackages/subfolders as well.

As for the second part of your question: I do not think it is possible and in my opinion you should not mix APIs.

Comment: but do i need to include the java files again for which javadoc already exists? can't i just append to the already existing javadocs? I mean everytime i create a new java file, I will have to create javadoc for the new as well as already existing java files? where is the reusability concept?

Comment: Reusability? I don't think this was a development goal of Javadoc-developers. Most people want an accurate documentation of the code, _as it is in the very moment_ that javadoc is executed. And the best way to ensure that is to overwrite everything which might be out-dated. In most SW projects I have participated Javadoc is executed at least once per night using a CI tool and a build manager like maven or ant. Of course, the generated documentation of distinct releases is saved in a repository and tagged accordingly as is done with other artifacts as well.